# Constructing predicate in Core data with many-to-one / one-to-many relationships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I can't find the way to do this: I just want to get all the pages in my library.

So, a function that should looks like:

```
func pages(inLibrary id: String) -> [Page] {
    //What is the predicate should I use to achieve this ? 
}
```

Thanks for your explanation.

[image]

Comment: So, `"book.library == %@", id`?

Comment: Thanks Larme, I'm just stupid :/. I was trying to do with "SUBQUERY" and and just find the same result, but yours is better :) From my example, is more "book.library.id == %@", id or "book.library == %@", libraryObject

Comment: Indeed, I missed the `id` property of Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (you can remove the `SELF.`, but it's for making easier explanations):

```
NSPredicate(format: "SELF.book.library.id == %@", id)
```

You retrieve the `Book` the `Pages` is "in", with `SELF.book` inside a Pages Fetch Request.

You can then retrieve the `Library` the `Book` is with `SELF.library` inside a Book Fetch Request.

You can use `SELF.id` to retrieve the `Library` from its `id` inside a `Library` Fetch Request.

By combination, you can use `SELF.book.library.id` to retrieve the `Library` from the `Pages`.

You can remove `SELF.`.